# Cannot move label in center of field

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to align css for google auth field, you can see on screenshot that label is not centered.

[image]

When I add on that label padding-top or margin-top, css is not added to the element.

Need help to figure out why.

This is HTML/jsx of button:

```
            <a className="button">
              <div>
                <span className="svgIcon t-popup-svg">
                  <svg className="svgIcon-use" width="25" height="37" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
                    <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                    // Here coming SVG CODE of icon
                    </g>
                  </svg>
                </span>
                <span className="button-label">Sign in with Google</span>
              </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

This is styles related to button:

```
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  font: inherit;
  outline: none;

  .button-label {
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 15px;
  }

  .svgIcon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
    height: 37px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Any advice how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `line-height: 37px;`
or
giving flex property to button

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
```

after that give padding according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `line-height:37px;` on `.button-label`